# android drawRect not drawing anything

Tags: android, canvas, drawrect

I've run into a wall with this basic drawRect not showing anything and I cannot figure out why.

### onDraw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(circle1x, circle1y, circleRadius, circlePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(circle2x, circle2y, circleRadius, circlePaint);

    canvas.drawRect(rect, rectPaint);
}
```

---

### setupCropping

Is running before the onDraw and is called from the View constructor to set up all the var's

```
private void setupCropping() {

    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    circleRadius = (int) (circleRadiusDp * scale + 0.5f);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    displayX = metrics.widthPixels;
    displayY = metrics.heightPixels;

    cropAreaY = displayY / 3;
    cropAreaX = displayX;

    //Setting up the circles for adjusting
    circle1x = displayX / 2;
    circle1y = displayY / 2 - (cropAreaY / 2);

    circle2x = displayX / 2;
    circle2y = displayY / 2 + (cropAreaY / 2);

    canvasPaint = new Paint();
    canvasPaint.setColor(0xffffff00);

    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(0xffffff00);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    rectPaint = new Paint();
    rectPaint.setColor(0xffffff00);

    rect = new Rect();
    rect.set(0, circle1y, 0, displayY - cropAreaY - circle1y);

}
```

The drawCircle works perfectly and draws as I'd expect it, I've checked the numbers being given to drawRect and they are set as they should be so I really don't know what could be going wrong here.

### Full View class

```
package com.samplersnapshoot.domiq.samplersnapshoot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * Created by domix on 14.8.2015..
 */
public class CroppingView extends View {

public final String TAG = "DEBUG";

private Canvas cropCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

private int displayX;
private int displayY;

private int circle1x = 0;
private int circle2x = 0;
private int circle1y = 0;
private int circle2y = 0;

private int circleRadiusDp = 20;
private int circleRadius = 100;

private int cropAreaX = 0;
private int cropAreaY = 0;

private Rect rect;

private Paint canvasPaint;
private Paint circlePaint;
private Paint rectPaint;

public CroppingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupCropping();
}

private void setupCropping() {

    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    circleRadius = (int) (circleRadiusDp * scale + 0.5f);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    displayX = metrics.widthPixels;
    displayY = metrics.heightPixels;

    cropAreaY = displayY / 3;
    cropAreaX = displayX;

    //Setting up the circles for adjusting
    circle1x = displayX / 2;
    circle1y = displayY / 2 - (cropAreaY / 2);

    circle2x = displayX / 2;
    circle2y = displayY / 2 + (cropAreaY / 2);

    canvasPaint = new Paint();
    canvasPaint.setColor(0xffffff00);

    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(0xffffff00);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    rectPaint = new Paint();
    rectPaint.setARGB(50, 135, 225, 255);

}

/*@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    displayX = widthMeasureSpec;
    displayY = heightMeasureSpec;
    invalidate();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}*/

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    //Getting bitmap
    getPath myPath = new getPath();
    final File myFile = myPath.getLastModifiedFile();

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread getCanvasBitmap = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inDither = true;
            opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            int i = 0;
            while (canvasBitmap == null && ++i < 500) {
                System.gc();

                Log.d(TAG, "Trying again: " + i);
                canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath(), opt);
            }

            latch.countDown();
        }
    };

    getCanvasBitmap.start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Turning into mutable bitmap
    myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
    try {
        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(myFile, "rw");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int bWidth = canvasBitmap.getWidth();
    int bHeight = canvasBitmap.getHeight();
    FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer map = null;
    try {
        map = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, bWidth*bHeight*4);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    canvasBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(map);
    canvasBitmap.recycle();
    this.canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bWidth, bHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    map.position(0);
    this.canvasBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(map);
    try {
        channel.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        randomAccessFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

    Log.d(TAG, "Display vars:" + displayX + " " + displayY);

    canvas.drawCircle(circle1x, circle1y, circleRadius, circlePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(circle2x, circle2y, circleRadius, circlePaint);

    rect = new Rect();
    rect.set(5, circle1y, displayX, displayY - cropAreaY - circle1y);

    canvas.drawRect(rect, rectPaint);


}
}
```

The class is far from well coded, I have yet to integrate a lot of functionality and clean it up.

Comment: `rect.set(0, circle1y, 0, displayY - cropAreaY - circle1y);` == vertical line :) on the left edge

Comment: I'm trying to make the rectangle touch both sides of the screen, am I suppose to set the right one to max X?

Comment: I suppose to set the right one to max X? **YES**  Set `Style` and `width` to `rectPaint` `rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);`

Comment: Please post your full custom View class. I'm sure I can help you solve your problem then.

Comment: Wow you forgot to put @DavidH in your comment so I didn't get a notification.

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, I might be on to something. How are you adding the View to your Activity? Through XML or at runtime?

Comment: Okay, updated my answer with the real issue in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rect.set(0, circle1y, 0, displayY - cropAreaY - circle1y);
```

Both your `left` and `right` coordinates are 0. Go figure.

It's

```
rect.set(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

EDIT:

Okay I managed to pinpoint the issue. The following line is in your `View` class

```
rect.set(5, circle1y, displayX, displayY - cropAreaY - circle1y);
```

Using the same calculations in your code, for a device with a 480x800 display, I'm getting the following coordinate values.

```
rect.set(5, 267, 480, 267);
```

Again, you have overlapping sides of your `Rect`; Both your `top` and `bottom` sides are on the same `Y` coordinate. This will produce a rectangle of 262 pixels wide and **ZERO HEIGHT**.

All you need to do is to update your coordinates calculation and supply the proper coordinates. Otherwise, your `Rect` should draw just fine.

Comment: They're 0 cause I want the rectangle to touch the edges on each side of the screen, so I set the right one to X

Comment: When is the onMeasure() suppose to be called cause it's not called when I put it in. Besides, can't I just use the display vars considering the view is taking up the entire screen (in immersive mode)

Comment: @Domiq It's supposed to be called on first layout, and also when there's change in any other layout in your Activity.

Comment: @Domiq You could try using displayX for the right coordinates. That should work.

Comment: @Domiq Oh I think onMeasure() IS GETTING called. I think the problem lies in the fact that your rect.set() is done in the View's constructor, which is before onMeasure() is called. Some small changes considering this should fix it.

Comment: Tried it, with all the changes but I still don't get anything, I've put all the position calculation into onDraw just before drawing and removed displayMetrics while using display vars for onMeasure. And I don't even get the circles now.

Comment: And for some reason displayX after onMeasure is set to 1073742592, displayY to 1073743104